# Set up a link in slack reminder

Tags: slack

Is there any way to set up a slack `/reminder` with a link in the text?

**Example:**

```
/reminder me Hey! Check out the weather in https://www.yr.no/place/Norway/ every weekday
```

When I try to type this on Slack, I get the following message:

*/reminder me Hey! Check out the weather in https://www.yr.no/place/Norway/ every weekday* is not a valid command. In Slack, all messages that start with the "/" character are interpreted as commands.

If you are trying to send a message and not run a command, try preceding the "/" with an empty space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yep, it is always nice to include links to Docs, Jira, etc. To include a link, use quotation marks when you describe what to remind. 
e.g., /remind @Trump to "use Google Scholar when searching for scientific  evidence https://scholar.google.com" every weekday.

Comment: Yes! It works perfectly, I didn't think about it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

Slack now lets you link text within its editor (without posting the full URL) so you can set:

> /remind me "Hey! Check out [the weather in Norway](https://www.yr.no/place/Norway/)" every weekday

which is a little cleaner

Comment: For me, this only works if I add the link certain ways. If I highlight the text and paste the link it does not work (though it changes the text in the editor to resemble a hyperlink and looks like it will work). If I select the text and open the link editor (command + shift + U for me) then the text will actually be linked in the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that works in my case:

```
/remind me Here is <https://www.yr.no/place/Norway|the link> in 1 min
```

***Note!*** No embedded links, just paste it as a plain text.

And the outcome is:

[image: the outcome]

Comment: Tried `/remind #général "@canal Weekly meeting dans 10mn, avez-vous <https://app.clickup.com/xxxxxxx/v/l/6-900302223377-1|préparé vos notes> ?" at 15:50 every Monday` and that didn't work well, the displayed link was broken. The pipe `|` was misinterpretated in this case. (although that is what I use for links, usually...) Maybe this particular link format is causing a bug? Also note that the `@canal` doesn't work either, so don't just copy blindly, I'm experimenting.